# Why won the if statement execute?

Tags: java

I wrote a simple program in Java which writes a word backwards. Trying to check if "hello" works. In `if`-statement I'm checking that string is equal to "olleh". Could anyone see why the if statement won't execute.

```
public class MyProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x = "hello";
        System.out.println(back(x));
    }

    public static String back(String str) {
        String y = " ";
        String temp = " ";
        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char lets = str.charAt(i);
            y += Character.toString(lets);
            System.out.println(y);
            if (y.equals("olleh")) {
                System.out.println("nice");
            }
        }
        return y;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: Why do you put a space in your reversed string?

Comment: Seems to be working. Can you tell exactly what error you get?

Comment: I think "nice" should execute at the end of the for loop and it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
 public class MyProgram
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    String  x = "hello";



    System.out.println(back(x));





    }


      public static String back(String str )
      {

          String temp = "";
        for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char lets = str.charAt(i);
            temp = temp + lets;

        }

        if (temp.equals("olleh")) {
            System.out.println("nice");
        }
        return temp;

    }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but still not executing the if statement  for some reason.          output looks like the following
 ol
 oll
 olle
 olleh
 olleh

Comment: i have edited my above post run it again you will get the required output

Comment: got it ??? or still have any doubt

Comment: if my answer has solved your problem either upvote my answer or accept answer

Comment: Got it thanks a lot !!!!!  Th space in the quotes added that space in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you will initialize `y` variable to empty string instead of space your if-statement will execute and print "nice". Also you do not need a `temp` string as you don't use it. You probably want to return you reverted string back (alternatively you can make your method void and remove the return statement).

```
public static String back(String str) {
    String y = "";
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char lets = str.charAt(i);
        y += Character.toString(lets);
        System.out.println(y);
        if (y.equals("olleh")) {
            System.out.println("nice");
        }
    }
    return y;
}
```

By the way, it's better to use `StringBuilder` when you're concatenating strings in a loop.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes sense it was starting off as an empty space and adding from there.   Thanks again for the help!!!!!

Comment: @D.Santisi you're welcome. Feel free to mark an answer as accepted if it resolved your problem